# Is there a way to observe an Arraylist's size as it changes via databinding?

Tags: java, android, data-binding, view, android-databinding

Basically my ViewModel holds the following POJO as a MutableLiveData:

```
public class SubredditAddition {

    private final ArrayList<Keyword> mKeywords = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

And I want a view to disappear if `mKeyword.size() > 0`

Currently, I have the following line in my view:

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.subredditAddition.keywords.size() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

However, changes to the mKeywords array size does not affect the view's visibility. How can I make the view react to the ArrayList's size in realtime?

Update:

My SubredditAddition class now uses ObservableArraylist, like so:

```
public class SubredditAddition {

    private final ObservableArrayList<Keyword> mKeywords = new ObservableArrayList<>();

}
```

My ViewModel looks like this, holding a SubredditAddition in a MutableLiveData:

```
public class SubredditSelectionViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<SubredditAddition> mSubredditAddition = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public SubredditSelectionViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);

        mSubredditAddition.setValue(new SubredditAddition());
    }
}
```

And my Fragment has the following code to update the keywords:

```
public class SubredditSelectionFragment extends Fragment {

    private void saveTag(Keyword newKeyword) {
        SubredditSelectionViewModel viewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SubredditSelectionViewModel.class);

         ObservableArrayList<Keyword> keywords = viewModel.getSubredditAddition().getKeywords();

        keywords.add(newKeyword);
    }
}
```

My XML view looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout ....
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.subredditAddition.keywords.size() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">
```

However, my UI still does not get updated once I add a keyword via the `saveKeyword()` method in my Fragment. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. ArrayList itself is not Observable. Either you want to push a change to your registry onec you added/removed items, or you use an `ObservableArrayList` instead.

It behaves like the ArrayList and you'r able to use `get()` and `set()`

```
public class SubredditAddition {
    public final ObservableList<Keyword> mKeywords = new ObservableArrayList<>();
}
```

Make it `public` if you don't provide getter and setters.

Even if the solution above may work, its not recommended since it will not get updated if an item in the List get updated but not the list itself.

Better solution is to create an ObservableInt or ObservableBoolean and update this onec the Lists setter has been called.

Example:

```
ObservableInt listVisibility = new ObservableInt(View.GONE);

public void setListData(List<Keyword> data) { 
   // update your list
   listVisibility.set( data.size() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

and finally in your Layout:

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.listVisibility}"
```

Comment: I tried this, however there was still no update to the UI. Does SubredditAddition have to extend BaseObservable or something?

Comment: ObservableList notify the view onec it's changed (set() called). Make sure that it's public and you don't have any getter/setter. Take care: It only notify if your List ADD or REMOVE items. Do you want to listen for changes in Keyword aswell? If yes, ill update the answer for a solution

Comment: I want to notify when an item is added or removed. Right now I do list.add(). Am I supposed to use list.set() instead?

Comment: It depends what you use. Using an BaseObservable/Observable with registry or ObservableList :-)

Comment: Please see my update in the post to see how I'm structuring my code; its still not working even after using observablelist